# How to enable ligatures for emdash/endash in LuaTeX ?

Tags: fonts, fontspec, luatex, ligatures, punctuation

I cannot switch on ligatures for emdash (---) and endash (--) in LuaLaTeX. Here is my test file:

```
% !Mode:: "TeX:UTF-8"
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
    \setmainfont{Cambria}
    \setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Calibri}
\usepackage{ifluatex,ifxetex}
\begin{document}

\ifxetex
    This is XeTeX
\else\ifluatex
    This is LuaTeX
\fi\fi

\section{rmfamily}
\rmfamily
\begin{enumerate}
\item <<double quote>> by ligatures \verb|<<ligatures>>|
\item «double quotes» by symbols \verb|«double quotes»|
\item en--dash by ligatures \verb|en--dash|
\item em---dash by ligatures \verb|em---dash|
\item en–dash by symbol \verb|en–dash|
\item em—dash by symbol \verb|em—dash|
\end{enumerate}

\section{sffamily}
\sffamily
\begin{enumerate}
\item <<double quote>> by ligatures \verb|<<ligatures>>|
\item «double quotes» by symbols \verb|«double quotes»|
\item en--dash by ligatures \verb|en--dash|
\item em---dash by ligatures \verb|em---dash|
\item en–dash by symbol \verb|en–dash|
\item em—dash by symbol \verb|em—dash|
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

When it is compiled with XeLaTeX, `\sffamily` loaded with the obsolete option `Mapping=tex-text`

```
    \setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Calibri}
```

activates the ligatures `---` and `--`, but in LuaTeX this options seemed to be equivalent to `Ligatures=TeX`, so that I don't know how to restore default (in LaTeX) behavior of these two ligatures.

> Is it bug or a feature, introduced in a recent version of the `fontspec` package?

I've checked that the ligatures still work as expected under LuaTeX if I don't set OTF fonts by the commands

```
    \setmainfont{Cambria}
    \setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Calibri}
```

Comment: I'm curious about your very last statement. Do you have an example where the ligatures work with Calibri as the font with LuaTeX?

Comment: @Alan, there is no such example.

Comment: With XeTeX, I had to use the `xunicode` package to get em-dash working. Maybe you're missing that? `\usepackage{xunicode}`.

Comment: @Raphink: As it is said in `lualatex-doc.pdf` the package `xunicode` should not be used with `lualatex`: _Package xunicode’s main feature is to ensure that the usual control sequences for non-ASCII
characters (such as \’e) do the right thing in a Unicode context. It could probably work with
LuaTEX, but explicitly checks for X ETEX only. However, fontspec uses a trick to load it anyway.
So, you can’t load it explicitly, but you don’t need to, since fontspec already took care of it._

Comment: good to know.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The TeX-ligatures in luatex are not a font property, they are "faked" features implemented in the font loader code. The problem could be the bug in the luaotfload/context code reported some month ago:

http://archive.contextgarden.net/message/20110310.181448.288f2a38.en.html

I think it has been corrected in context but I doubt that the new code has already found its way in luaotfload.

You can test the font directly (to exclude a fontspec problem and to test the both modes)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luaotfload}
\begin{document}
 \font\test="Calibri:mode=node;+tlig" 

 \font\testb="Calibri:mode=base;+tlig" 
 \test -- --- abc 

 \testb -- --- abc 
\end{document}
```

Comment: can this be fixed temporarily by redefining `\fontspec_init` to set `\l_fontspec_mode_tl` to `{base}` instead of `{node}`? My minimal testing says yes, but I suspect that will screw up other things with other fonts. If so, is there a way to do this on a font by font basis?

Comment: @Alan: The issue is font dependant. Some fonts works with mode=base, some with mode=node, and some none at all. You can change the mode on font basis with the "Renderer" option: `\setmainfont[Renderer=Basic,Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}`

Comment: thanks.  I've updated my answer to reflect your comments.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: It's been a while since this issue was discussed and I'm surprised to find that the situation in LuaLaTeX still seems to be the same. I still need to set `Renderer=Basic` to get the em-dash with Times New Roman (`\textemdash` works fine though, even w/o this). Anyway: I'm wondering what the negative consequences of this are. I mean, "Basic" sounds like LuaLaTeX will not perform at its best...

Comment: @Christoph: There is currently - as far as I know - no development in the font handling in lualatex. The code in context is evolving but the changes are not transfered to luaotfload. Partly because keeping pace with the context code is painful (there is no real documentation), partly because the author of luaotfload has other things on his mind.

Answer (score 11):

This is partially a property of the *font*, and not a problem with `fontspec`.  XeLaTeX and LuaTeX implement the ligature replacement with different mechanisms. XeLaTeX uses a teckit mapping file, whereas LuaTeX uses `luaotfload` to do the conversion.  The latter is somehow dependent on how the font actually implements certain characters. Changing the font to Linux Libertine O, for example, causes the ligatures to appear correctly.

**Update**

As noted by Ulrike Fischer, you can change this on a font-by-font basis for fonts that don't work by specifying a value for the `Renderer` key when you load the font. There are two possible (relevant) values for this key in LuaLaTeX: `Full` (default) and `Basic`.  Loading certain fonts with the `Basic` renderer will allow the ligatures. This will not work for all fonts, however.  For more discussion, see the following thread on `comp.text.tex`: [en-dash and em-dash in luatex](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/83f1590dca799b72).

The following modified version of your document shows how the problem doesn't arise with Linux Libertine O, and how it can be fixed for Cambria. (Calibri) works the same way.

As Ulrike notes in her answer, a more robust fix will propagate to `luaotfload` at some point in the future.

```
% !Mode:: "TeX:UTF-8"
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX}}
    \setmainfont{Cambria}
    \setsansfont{Calibri}
\usepackage{ifluatex,ifxetex}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}

\ifxetex
    This is XeTeX
\else\ifluatex
    This is LuaTeX

\fi\fi

\section{Cambria}

\begin{enumerate}
\item <<double quote>> by ligatures \verb|<<ligatures>>|
\item «double quotes» by symbols \verb|«double quotes»|
\item en--dash by ligatures \verb|en--dash|
\item em---dash by ligatures \verb|em---dash|
\item en–dash by symbol \verb|en–dash|
\item em—dash by symbol \verb|em—dash|
\end{enumerate}

\section{Linux Libertine O}
\fontspec{Linux Libertine O}\selectfont
\begin{enumerate}
\item <<double quote>> by ligatures \verb|<<ligatures>>|
\item «double quotes» by symbols \verb|«double quotes»|
\item en--dash by ligatures \verb|en--dash|
\item em---dash by ligatures \verb|em---dash|
\item en–dash by symbol \verb|en–dash|
\item em—dash by symbol \verb|em—dash|
\end{enumerate}

\section{Cambria + Basic Renderer}
\fontspec[Renderer=Basic]{Cambria}\selectfont
\begin{enumerate}
\item <<double quote>> by ligatures \verb|<<ligatures>>|
\item «double quotes» by symbols \verb|«double quotes»|
\item en--dash by ligatures \verb|en--dash|
\item em---dash by ligatures \verb|em---dash|
\item en–dash by symbol \verb|en–dash|
\item em—dash by symbol \verb|em—dash|
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: your notation is important, but what to do if I want to use Calibri, Cambria, Times New Roman, Pallatino Linotype or many other fornt, which do not support such ligatures? As to me, I have macro written for WinEdt, wich convers --- and -- to appropriate symbols as soon as I type in --- or --. But what to do all others who have no similar macro?

Comment: @Igor What you are doing is appropriate. There may be other ways to patch the font using lua, but I don't know how to do this. I would wait a bit to see if a more complete answer appears. (I edited my answer a bit to remove an inaccuracy in the explanation.)

Comment: Looking through `fontspec.pdf`, I concluded that `Render` key can acquire either `Basic` or `Full` value, and the latter is default. As to XeLaTeX, allowed values are `AAT/ICU/Graphite`. Is that correct?

Comment: @Igor, yes that is correct.  But AAT fonts are Mac only, and require a different driver (`xdv2pdf`) which I don't think is actively being developed. Graphite font support is minimal.  See [Using Graphite fonts with XeTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4324/2693).

Answer (score 7):

I can't compete with the level of discussion between Ulrike and Alan. But thanks to the [link](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/83f1590dca799b72) provided by Alan, I found out how to get an en-dash with another of those Win-fonts: Corbel. I ran into the same problem two weeks ago and thanks to your help I know now how to handle it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Renderer=Basic,Ligatures=TeX]{Corbel}
\begin{document}
-- --- abc 
\end{document}
```

I get the en-dash and the em-dash this way. 
Or did I miss something and this way to get dashes is obsolete?

Comment: I guess this may well be font-dependent.

Comment: This answer solves the two problems with quotes and en-dashed in this question This answer solves the two problems with quotes and en-dashed in this question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118008/how-to-use-en-dash-with-cambria-fonts for Cambria font.