# luatex 0.76 failed to generate some ligatures

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, ligatures

I installed texlive 2013 today. After installation, `luatex` cannot generate ligatures for "fi fl ff", but it can for ``` '' ---`.`xetex` works perfectly here, after update.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={Common,Rare,TeX}]{EB Garamond}

\begin{document}

\Huge{ffi fl fi `` '' ---}

\end{document}
```

[image: <code>lualatex</code> version:]

---

UPDATE: I tried to use the method described here: 
[How to enable ligatures for emdash/endash in LuaTeX ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20580/how-to-enable-ligatures-for-emdash-endash-in-luatex)
And `luatex` can generate ligatures correctly. So is my problem related to `fontspec`?

[image]

Comment: The last version had a bug that prevented node mode from being set properly. This will be fixed in the next upload (probably today).

Comment: In my just updated system the output is correct.

Comment: Confirmed. Everything works perfect now. Please close this question.

Comment: No. Seems I used the `xelatex` to compile MWE. Still waiting for the update.

Comment: I was just having very weird effects too which got solved after I deleted the luatex-cache in `~/.texlive2013/texmf-var/`. This forces the cache to be rebuilt (manually calling luaotfload-tool didn’t do the trick).

Comment: Tried that method, but it did not work for me.

Comment: the newest (May 19) version now can generate the ligature, but those ligature are not 'copyable'/