# How to use en-dash with Cambria fonts?

Tags: luatex, punctuation, fontspec, ligatures, opentype

When using non-TeX fonts in LuaTeX I can produce en-dashes in the usual way by typing two dashes together `--`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}%use luatex
\setmainfont{Cambria}
\begin{document} 
Hello -dashes- --en dashes-- ---em dashed---
\end{document}
```

[image: cambria]

Is there a workaround?

For comparison, here it is the result using the default font:

[image: default]

**And in case this related:** I have a similar problem with `` and '' to type double quotation marks with Cambria.

Comment: `\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Cambria}`

Comment: @tohecz, thank for the pointer: I found the solution in this undervoted answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20689/1871.

Comment: @egreg, `Ligatures=TeX` solves the `` '' problem, in addition `Renderer=Basic` solves the problem with en-dash, as in this answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20689/1871. In summary this line solves both original problems `\setmainfont[Renderer=Basic,Ligatures=TeX]{Cambria}`