# Why does using small caps break endash ligatures in lualatex?

Tags: luatex, ligatures, luaotfload

I've spent most of my day trying to migrate a project from `pdftex` to`lualatex`. The experience has been mostly positive but there are a few gotchas I can't make heads or tails of.

Most recently I've just noticed that the standard texish ligatures for endash and emdash (i.e `--` is typeset as – and `---` becomes —) have gone  A.W.O.L on me when located in small caps formatted references. This is unfortunate as I use endash in Bible verse references that are typeset in the margins using small-caps.

I have reviewed the info in [How to enable ligatures for emdash/endash in LuaTeX ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20580/5100) but this seems to be a different issue.

Here is a MWE showing the issue (compile with lualatex):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{luatextra}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine}

\begin{document}
Test -- endash and --- emdash

{\scshape Test -- endash and --- emdash}
\end{document}
```

Which for me produces:

[image: small cap dash ligatures missing]

What is the culprit here and how do I fix it?

Comment: I can confirm it; and it doesn't happen with TeX Live 2012, so I think it's a bug in `luaotfload`

Comment: I do not have Linux Libertine installed. However I  tested with Latin Modern and Minion Pro; it compiles and shows no problem. I suppose it's specifically a problem with Linux Libertine.

Comment: Also tested here with Garamond Pro; no issues on MikTeX 2.9. I can reproduce the issue with Linux Libertine, though. So as @Bernard said, it seems to be specific to Libertine.

Comment: Indeed, I tried some other fonts and none seems to have the problem.

Comment: However (comment aside) I tried to test with Heuristica and … LuaLaTeX doesn't find the font, while XeLaTeX does!

Comment: My tests suggested it is Libertine specific, too, and also Lua specific (no problem with XeLaTeX). Also, loading `libertine` does not work any magic although it does define `endash` etc. which seemed possibly promising.

Comment: using TL2014 it doesn't find the font under that name ` `\setmainfont{LinLibertine_R}` works but shows `--` as you report. However if you use `{\scshape Test – endash and — emdash}` with the characters directly then it works.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, but I was aware entering the Unicode symbol directly would work. Unfortunately these ligatures are mostly found in a shared repository of snippets that I `\input`  from and they need to continue working for some folks still compiling with non UTF8 savvy LaTeX engines so I cannot just replace them all. I need a solution that knows what to do with `--`.

Comment: @Caleb yes I suspected so but just gave the comment as to the situation in texlive 2014 (ie the latest pre-release test of everything) to help anyone who knows more about the opentype font setup to find the problem

Comment: [Reported.](http://www.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2014/078028.html)

Comment: Hans fixed it. The new code will be part of the next version of Luaotfload.

Comment: @phg Awesome, thanks for the news. Is there a place I can get a patch to tide me over until the next release? I looked a the [Github repo for luaotfload](https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/commits/texlive2014) but the latest commit is 3 weeks ago so obviously this code isn't there.

Comment: @Caleb Since there’s a major subsystem rewrite underway I keep the changes in [my repo](https://github.com/phi-gamma/luaotfload) until I’m confident they don’t break everything when merged into master. I haven’t checked whether the fix applies to older versions.

Comment: Has the bug fix been released to the CTAN yet? I have version 2.4-4 of `luaotfload`, dated 2014/05/18, and the bug's still there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bug fix has been released to CTAN as of the v2.5-1 release.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{luatextra}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine}

\begin{document}
Test -- endash and --- emdash

{\scshape Test -- endash and --- emdash}
\end{document}
```

with

> `luaotfload.sty     2014/07/16 v2.5-1 OpenType layout system`

gives

[image]

Comment: Any suggestion for a hack to get it done with luatex 0.95.0 (which is currently in debian)?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea, and no way to test anything out on debian right now. :( If you ask about this in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends), someone may have helpful ideas.