# Graphite with Awami 1.0 not working

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

I have been trying to no avail to make the Urdu font Awami Nastaliq work in xelatex (TexLive 2017). What am I doing wrong? The following example doesn't even produce a pdf. I get the error "Error 256 (driver return code) generating output; file Awami.pdf may not be valid," although I get no warning that it hasn't found Awami or is having problems with the font.

The comments show that others are not having this problem. I have installed TL2017 portable on Manjaro 17.0.5 and Xubuntu 16.04, but it seems to make no difference.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[AutoFakeBold=2.0,Script=Arabic,Scale=1, WordSpace=6,Renderer=Graphite]{Awami Nastaliq}
\usepackage[RTLdocument,extrafootnotefeatures]{bidi}

\begin{document}
بر صغیر پاک و ہند کے اکثر علاقوں میں بولی اور سمجھی جانے والی زبان جس کے لغات میں پراکرت نیز غیر پراکرت، دیسی لفظوں کے ساتھ ساتھ عربی فارسی ترکی اور کچھ یورپی زبانوں کے الفاظ بھی شامل ہیں اور جس کی قواعد میں عہد بہ عہد تصرفات اور مقامی اختلافات کے باوجود آریائی اثر غالب ہے۔ (ابتداءً ہندوی یا ہندی کے نام سے متعارف رہی۔ ابتدا یا آغاز کے بارے میں مختلف نظریات ہیں : بعض لوگ سورسینی یا اب بھرنش کی جدید ترقی یافتہ یا ترمیم شدہ شکل بتاتے ہیں جس نے عہد غزنوی کے لگ بھگ نیا روپ نکالنا شروع کیا اور جو تقریباً چودھویں صدی سے ضبط تحریر میں آئی۔ منظوم اردو کو ریختہ کہتے تھے۔
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you seen https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4324 ?  It’s an old question, and the situation may have changed since then, but it’s a start.

Comment: I get output that looks as expected when I remove `Script=Arabic` from your example.  `fontspec` complains that the font doesn’t contain the Arabic script.

Comment: @Therese Yes, it's the only one I have found, and it doesn't seem to help. According to that solution, a pdf file is generated with only one bracket.

Comment: That's funny. I noticed that it was complaining. But it doesn't seem to make a difference if I leave it or delete it. In both cases I don't get a pdf. I should add that if I use other Urdu fonts, I have not problems generating a pdf file.

Comment: I get a nice PDF with XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (TeX Live 2017), and bidi 2017/10/11, v31.5; do you have a different version of `bidi`?

Comment: I have the same XeTeX Version (the frozen one), but my bidi is older, bidi 2017/05/19 v30.6. So that must be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simpler than I thought. After nearly going crazy I found out that I only had to move the folder containing the Awami font into the TTF folder in /usr/share/fonts.

As this answer is related to linux and not latex, perhaps this question should to be deleted. The combination Graphite & Awami is now working well.